# Get input field value by appending properties within a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm wondering if this is at all possible to do...

Essentially I'm storing information of the form (i.e. select, input, textarea) within a json object.

```
var inputs = {
    "name": {
        errorMsg: "Please enter a name!",
        inputName: "name",
        inputType: "input"
    }
}
```

From there, I want to construct the input value with jQuery such as:

```
$('input#name').val();
```

and have it actually return the value of the input field.

I was thinking of maybe doing something like this:

```
var inType = inputs.name.inputType;
var inName = inputs.name.inputName;
var stringType = $("'" + inType + "#" + inName + "'");
alert(stringType.val());
```

But that gives me an undefined value.

Here is the html I'm using:

```
 <input name="name" id="name" value="test" />
```

I've noticed that if I add add to the json object: `value: $('input#name').val()` after `inputType` and then go `alert(inputs.name.value)` it gives me the proper value. So should I construct the string and then prop it to the my `inputs` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var stringType = $("'" + inType + "#" + inName + "'");`

The quotes are not necessary. this should be:

`var stringType = $(inType + "#" + inName);`

Comment: I was staring at that for way too long. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
var inType = inputs.name.inputType;
var inName = inputs.name.inputName;

var selector = inType + '#' + inName ;
var stringType = $(selector);
```